# Laravel with Angularjs Validating json requests bad response

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ajax, laravel-5

My webapp has Laravel as backend framework which provides a Restful API and in the fronend Angularjs is running.
I send different requests through the api and receive the responses and based on the code of response and data included, appropriate messages are shown to user.

Recently when I send requests using PUT method or POST method, when the data has problem in validation process and Laravel should respond with a 422 code in JSON format, instead I receive a text/html response with code 200. and then everything goes wrong.

This does not happen on my local machine, Only when I test the app in production environment this happens.

I also tested UnAuthorized response which is sent with 403 code, and it works flawlessly.

I tested both the automatic validation error for Laravel (as described in documentation: When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.) and also using the following method:

```
return response()->json(compact('errors'),422);
```

I should mention that I use following methods to send AJAX requests:

```
    function save(data, url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: angular.toJson(data)
        });
    }
    function update(data, url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: url + data.id,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: angular.toJson(data)
        });
    }
```

needless to say I became totally confused!

---

**UPDATE**: It seems to be a problem with Laravel validation process. when the validation runs, request become erroneous. see the following piece of code:

```
public function altUpdate(Request $request){
    $this->authorize('editCustomer', $this->store);
    if (!$request->has('customer')){
        return response()->json(["message"=>"Problem in received data"],422);
    }
    $id = $request->customer['id'];
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'mobile' => "required|digits:11|unique:customers,mobile,$id,id,store_id,$this->store_id",
        'phone' => 'digits_between:8,11',
        'email' => "email|max:255|unique:customers,email,$id,id,store_id,$this->store_id",
    ];
    //return response()->json(["problem in data"],422); //this one works properly if uncommented
    $validator = Validator::make($request->customer,$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        $errors = $validator->errors()->all();
        Log::info($errors);
        return response()->json(["problem in data"],422);//this one is received in client side as a text/html response with code 200
    }

    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $customer->update(wrapInputs($request->all()));

    if ($request->tags) {
        $this->syncTags($request->tags, $customer);
    }
    $message = "Customer updated successfully!";
    return response()->json(compact('message'));
}
```

I still don't know what's the problem of validation process. this code is working on my local machine without any problems but on the production server problem occurs.

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Normally a 200 can happen from a request that fails but does not throw a proper error code. It can be good to set http_response_code(500) as the first line in the response code so it will default to 500 instead of 200.

Comment: No, nothing in logs. where I should use the set_http_response(500)? before validation? @shylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got that.
I had added a language file and the file was encoded in UTF-8-BOM, when I converted that file to UTF-8 without BOM things become correct.

the file was resources/lang/[the language]/validation.php and because of the encoding problem the headers were being sent while processing this file.

This question also helped me to find the problem:
[Laravel redirect::route is showing a message between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136778/laravel-redirectroute-is-showing-a-message-between-page-loads)