# Showing redirect page when using localization in controllers

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5

When using localization in controllers, the symfony "Redirecting to $page" is visible for 2-3 seconds. When I remove localization from the controller, the problem goes away.

So, this shows me the "Redirecting to $page" page for a second or two,

```
public function processPassword(Authenticatable $user, Request $request)
{
    [..] 
    $message = trans("translation.password_changed");

    return redirect()->route('edit-password')->with('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => $message]);

}
```

and this does not

```
public function processPassword(Authenticatable $user, Request $request)
{
    [..] 
    $message = "Your password has been changed";

    return redirect()->route('edit-password')->with('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => $message]);
}
```

How is this possible and how do I add localization to my controllers?

Comment: Looks like you might find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136778/laravel-redirectroute-is-showing-a-message-between-page-loads

Comment: Could you log `$message` before return from controller? Like: `Log::info( $message )`

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos, that seems to be the same issue. Thank you!

Comment: @SerhiiTopolnytskyi, thank you for your reply. I could, but the message content does display fine on the redirected view. is there a other reason why I should log this?